# How to setup codereview with gitblit

Tags: gitblit

We are using Gitblit to manage our repositories, and recently we want to setup a codereview process.

I tried to search `gitblit+codereview` with google, but I can't find any useful message.

We don't want to discard out current Gitblit, we want to build the codereview process on it.

Can any one help me?

The version of Gitblit is v1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use the built-in Tickets feature for simple reviews.
2. You could add UpSource, ReviewBoard, Gerrit, or whatever review solution to your infrastructure.

Comment: How to add UpSource to the infrastrcture, have any guideline?